# Why can't this be done?

Tags: java

```
class A {
    A(int x) { System.out.println("constructor A"); } }

class B extends A {
    B() { System.out.println(" constructor B"); } }

public class C {
    public static void main(String args[]) { B b = new B(); } }
```

It says constructor from class A can't be applied for given types.

Comment: It won't matter since there's only one public class.

Comment: You need to provide a default constructor in Class A for this to work fine, because java requires implicit super constructor when extended, which is undefined in your case or call super constructor in B.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to call the constructor `A(int x)` explicitly in your constructor `B()`. I.e., you have to write

```
class B extends A {
   B() {
       super(<<< insert some int here>>>);
       System.out.println(" constructor B");
   } 
}
```

If you do not add such a super call, then java will insert `super();` for you which would try to call `A()`. As there is no constructor `A()` you receive the error that your constructor cannot be applied for the argument types.

Answer (score 1):

Its always good to have a default constructor in a class if your writing a paramterized one.

```
class A {
    A(){System.out.println("Default A");}
    A(int x) { System.out.println("constructor A"); } }

class B extends A {
    B() { System.out.println(" constructor B"); } }

public class C {
    public static void main(String args[]) { B b = new B(); } }
```

Answer (score 0):

If we don't specify a constructor to a class A, then a default constructor with no args will be associated to the class, if you specify one/more constructor to the class A, then you have to use one of them each time you want to create an object from this class.when a class B extend a class A, then  constructors have to call one  constructor of the parent class ( A ) by `super()` , if you don't specify a constructor to A then it's implecitly called be  the constructor of B, if you explecitly defined constructor of A , then You have to call it when you create constructor of  B like this :

```
B() {  super(0)/*this call should be if the first line, you have to pass your default args if the constructor have args*/;
       System.out.println(" constructor B"); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

what you are seeing is `constructor chaining`, [read](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html)

snippet from the link.

```
If a constructor does not explicitly invoke a superclass constructor, the Java compiler
automatically inserts a call to the no-argument constructor of the superclass. If the super
class does not have a no-argument constructor, you will get a compile-time error. Object 
does have such a constructor, so if Object is the only superclass, there is no problem.
```